# Unable to run the actions.py file with RASA for creating a Chatbot

Tags: python-3.x, webhooks, chatbot, rasa-core, rasa

I'am trying to build a chatbot using Rasa using NLU and Core.

All the necessary packages/libraries are installed.The data, stories and action files are also created.

However while running actions.py file, it is not connecting, i;m getting the below message

```
       (RASA) C:\Users\anbharadwaj\Desktop\Internal Chatbot 21\news>python -m rasa_sdk --actions 
       actions
       2020-04-13 14:35:12 INFO     rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Starting action endpoint server...
```

Please help me what is the cause of the problem and how to fix it

```
    Versions using:

    Python - 3.7.3

    Rasa_sdk - 1.4.0

    Rasa_nlu - 0.15.1

    rasa_core - 0.14.5

    tensorflow - 1.13.1
```

Have tried with almost all versions with Anaconda, and Rasa libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the logs are fine, it means that the Action Server has started, but you should see also the name(s) of the action(s) registered (defined in your stories).

I would try to start Rasa Action Server using Rasa

```
rasa run actions
```

You can confirm it is running invoking `http://localhost:5055/`, you get Requested URL / not found but at least you know you can connect to it.

Comment: I think my action server is running but how can I check if it is working. Is it possible to get a positive feedback instead of "URL not found": e.g. requesting `http://localhost:5055/registered_action_name` ?

Comment: Nope, that doesnt seem possible. Another option is to look at the logs at startup, it should log the name of the registered actions, you can also add your own logging in the actions.py if you like

Comment: I found on this [website](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/api/action-server/) that I can test the functionality. In Postman i can send a request to `localhost:5055/webhook/` and a json body with e.g. `..."next_action": "action_get_current_date"...` to get an answer with Code 200 which is fine for me. `action_get_current_date` is a custom action which is registered on starting the action server (listed on startup)